# Firebase Role Authorization with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, aurelia

Currently to avoid having users that are not logged in enter any route without permission, I have this class set up:

```
export class AuthorizeStep {
  run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        let currentRoute = navigationInstruction.config;
        let loginRequired = currentRoute.auth && currentRoute.auth === true;

        if (!user && loginRequired) {
          return resolve(next.cancel(new Redirect('')));
        }

        return resolve(next());
      });
    });
  }
```

Which is called here:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    this.router = router;
    config.title = 'title';

    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'inicio'], name: 'inicio', moduleId: './modules/contacts/components/inicio', title: 'au-samples.contacts.mainPage' },
      { route: 'conta', name: 'conta', moduleId: './modules/admin/conta', title: 'accountMessages.account', auth: true},
      { route: 'contacts', name: 'contacts', moduleId: './modules/contacts/components/list', title: 'au-samples.contacts.contacts', auth: true},
      { route: ':id', name: 'contact-details', moduleId: './modules/contacts/components/details', auth: true },
      { route: ':id/edit', name: 'contact-edition', moduleId: './modules/contacts/components/edition', auth: true },
      { route: ':id/photo', name: 'contact-photo', moduleId: './modules/contacts/components/photo', auth: true }
    ]);
    config.mapUnknownRoutes('not-found');
    config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
  }
```

And all that runs fine, but I'd like for there to be a way for me to pull the data of a user, which I have the means to do, get its role (which I can do too) and check if the user has that role before gaining access to a specific route, I was wondering if I would need to do another class and call it in my configureRouter with a addPipelineStep, or what would be another way to enable role-based authorization by checking a variable (in this case, if an array contains a word).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I read your question correctly and you are able to retrieve user roles correctly, you're looking for a way to authorize access to certain routes based on a certain role a user can have.

Using pipeline-steps, you are quite free to figure out any implementation you prefer. You can make use of the `settings`-parameter on routes like this:

```
config.map([
  { 
    route: 'conta', 
    name: 'conta', 
    moduleId: './modules/admin/conta', 
    title: 'accountMessages.account', 
    auth: true,
    settings: {
      role: 'admin' /* or any naming of choice */
    }
  }
]);
```

Then in a pipeline step, you can check for this attribute and restrict access based on whether a user has it or not:

```
run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        let currentRoute = navigationInstruction.config;
        let loginRequired = currentRoute.auth && currentRoute.auth === true;

        if (!user && loginRequired) {
          return resolve(next.cancel(new Redirect('')));
        }

        // hasRole checks the user roles for the role set on the route
        if (currentRoute.settings && currentRoute.settings.role) {
           if (!user.hasRole(currentRoute.settings.role) {
              return resolve(next.cancel(new Redirect('')));
           }
        }

        return resolve(next());
      });
    });
  }
```

You are obviously free to code this in any way you prefer, this is more of a general idea.